# context must be a dict rather than tuple Django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to get form data through POST method but got "context must be a dict rather than tuple" error.I have google it much, according to the Django 1.11's docs we Just need to use a regular dictionary instead of a Context instance.
I'm stuck here, help me please!

Here's the error:

```
TypeError at /docker/auth/
context must be a dict rather than tuple.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/docker/auth/
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
context must be a dict rather than tuple.
Exception Location: /Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/context.py in make_context, line 287
Python Executable:  /Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/abdul/Documents/IGui',
 '/Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 10 Jul 2017 10:12:30 +0000
```

Here's My views.py:

```
import json

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from . import forms
from django.http import HttpResponse

class DockerAuth(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.DockerAuthForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'dockerDep/docker_login.html', {})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        lform = forms.DockerAuthForm(request.POST)
        if lform.is_valid():
            data = lform.cleaned_data
            name = data['docker_name']
            password = data['docker_pass']
            args = {
                "mname": name,
                "mpass": password
            }
        return render(request, 'dockerDep/response.html', args)
```

Here's my forms.py:

```
from django.forms import forms
from .import models

class DockerAuthForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('docker_name', 'docker_pass')
        model = models.DockerAuth
```

Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class DockerAuth(models.Model):
    docker_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    docker_pass = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Here's my HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DOCKER</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="docker_name" title="Name">
        <input type="password" name="docker_pass" title="Password">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you get an error, **post it** along with the full traceback.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    lform = forms.DockerAuthForm(request.POST)
    if lform.is_valid():
        data = lform.cleaned_data()
        name = data['docker_name']
        password = data['docker_pass']
        args = {
            "mname": name,
            "mpass": password
        }
    return render(request, 'dockerDep/response.html', args)
```

You catch `args` as a parameter in this line:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

And a `*` means that it's a tuple. After this `args` **will** be a tuple. So if you don't change args in `lform.is_valid()` (scenarion where form is not valid), it will stay tuple and will be passed to `render()`

**EDIT**

Define a 'default' `context` (it will be empty)

Change `args` name for `context` to avoid collisions

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    lform = forms.DockerAuthForm(request.POST)
    context = {}
    if lform.is_valid():
        data = lform.cleaned_data()
        name = data['docker_name']
        password = data['docker_pass']
        context = {
            "mname": name,
            "mpass": password
        }
    return render(request, 'dockerDep/response.html', context)
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what you say, is there something wrong in my view?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid , do you mean this: `def post(self, request, args, kwargs):`. ?

Comment: @AbdulRehman change `args = {
            "mname": name,
            "mpass": password
        }` to `kwargs = {
            "mname": name,
            "mpass": password
        }`

Comment: Now it throws another error :  _KeyError_   for  `name = data['docker_name']`

Comment: @AbdulRehman it's not connected to this question. Probably, there is just no value with key 'docker_name'. Check the form or check for situations where the 'docker_name' isn't submitted.

Comment: it's coming from django form as I have paste my HTML template above!

Comment: @AbdulRehman you form doesn't have any of these fields: 'docker_name', 'docker_pass'

Comment: it still show same errors: `KeyError at /docker/auth/
'docker_name'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/docker/auth/
Django Version: 1.11.3
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'docker_name'
Exception Location: /Users/abdul/Documents/IGui/dockerDep/views.py in post, line 21
Python Executable: /Users/abdul/IstioVirEnv/bin/python`

Comment: @AbdulRehman create a new question and ask about the problem you have now so that not only I but also other people can help you. Your initial question was answered and changing question multiple times and then answering each subquestion inside comments is a bad idea